# How to add a switch toggle button to simple form in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using Rails 4 and Simple Form with Bootstrap.

I want that my checkbox will not like that:

```
<%= c.input :my_bool_field, label: false, class: "form-control" %>
```

[image]

but something like that (I have the CSS for that)

```
<label class="switch switch-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span></span>
</label>
```

[image]

I know I can use simple_form wrappers, but I find them a little bit confusing.. Can someone help me up creating the checkbox with that styling?

Comment: How did you finally solve your issue ?

Answer (score 7):

Could you go to this link and check it out "Switches". [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#switches)

[image]

I hope this example serves you, I'm currently use Bootstrap 4.3 and Rails 5.2;

Use a "custom-switch" in the form of your Model and its going to work:

-- model/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: employee, local: true) do |form| %>
 <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <%= form.check_box :active, class: "custom-control-input", id: "customSwitch1"   %>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Status: </label>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
     <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope helps you, I'm a newbie in Rails and Bootstrap.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

I found this project very useful and complete. It is based on twitter bootstrap: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

There is a [rails gem](https://github.com/rkallensee/bootstrap-toggle-rails) that embedded it :

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Rails Switchery gem found at https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery

Easy customization for bootstrap and ios style switches without trying to change simpleforms pre-built wrappers via the initializer or calling jquery functions in the view.

Comment: nope.. the above code is generating: `<div class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="designer[company_attributes][email_monthly_summary]"><label><input class="boolean optional user-success" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="designer[company_attributes][email_monthly_summary]" id="designer_company_attributes_email_monthly_summary"></label></div>`

Comment: Did you use input_field or just c.input?  Input_field should strip away the div wrapper.

Comment: There's also a js function for it to work but you may find the easiest approach is to use the switchery-gem found here:   https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery

Comment: the switchery-gem is a great answer - please move to be an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

just put checkbox inside

```
<label class="switch switch-primary">
     <%= f.input_field :my_bool_field, label: false, as: :boolean, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: thanks! it's a great progress the switch button appears but it is not reacting to clicks. here is the generated code: `<label class="switch switch-primary">
                       <input value="0" type="hidden" name="designer[company_attributes][email_monthly_summary]"><label><input label="false" class="boolean optional form-control user-success" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="designer[company_attributes][email_monthly_summary]" id="designer_company_attributes_email_monthly_summary"></label>
                      <span></span>
                  </label>`

Comment: that was because the span was outside the label. the order of the label and input are off. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Hi @GuyDubrovski trying to follow along here....did you get this working? or find another solution?