# rails checkbox to toggle button when using check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, toggle

I want to turn a checkbox into a toggle button in rails.
This is my code:

```
    <%= form_tag some_path do %>
      <% @vacancies.each do |vacancy| %> 
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "vacancies[]", vacancy.id %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Purchase" %>
    <% end %>
```

Is there any simple solution for a toggle when using this check_box_tag?

Comment: this answer probably can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700756/938947

Comment: My problem with these explanations is that they all work with a different check_box "syntax" such as: <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">. but I am using this form_tag syntax above. i use it because I fill an array with various objects that all have their own checkbox. Hope I am clear enough here.

Comment: You could use `check_box_tag` with some option to generate those different "syntax" and it should still work.